# Page refreshes after image upload

Tags: php, jquery

After I've uploaded an image my page refreshes and I'm not sure how to stop that from happening. I do have `e.preventDefault()`.

I do know that it might have to do with this line

```
if(in_array($ext, $allowed) && move_uploaded_file($temp, 'uploads/'.$name))
```

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');

    $(".upload-area").on('drop', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var files_list = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        var formData  = new FormData(); 

        for(i = 0; i < files_list.length; i++){
            formData.append('file[]', files_list[i]);
        }

        uploadData(formData);


        dropZone.ondragover = function(e){
            return false;
        }

        dropZone.ondragleave = function(e){
            return false;
        }
});

function uploadData(formdata){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            addThumbnail(response);
        }
    });
}

function addThumbnail(data){
    var len = $("#uploadfile div.thumbnail").length;

    var num = Number(len);
    num = num + 1;
    var src = data.src;

    // console.log(len);
    $("#thumbnail_"+num).append('<img src="'+src+'" width="100%" height="78%">');
}
```

my upload.php

```
$allowed = ['png', 'jpg'];

foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name)
{
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];

    $ext = explode('.', $name);
    $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

    if(in_array($ext, $allowed) && move_uploaded_file($temp, 'uploads/'.$name))
    {
        $return_arr = array("name" => $filename,"size" => $filesize);
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
```

my index.php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple>

  <!-- Drag and Drop container-->
  <div class="upload-area"  id="drop-zone">
    <h1>Drag and Drop file here<br/>Or<br/>Click to select file</h1>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a chance you could also post your HTML please?  Is the `.upload-area` element inside a `form`?  It's not your PHP code as this is being called via AJAX.

Comment: @Martin - I've added my html

Comment: I would guess that the form is being submitted for some reason, and that is causing your page reload. You can easily test it: set the `action` to equal `testpage.html` and carry out the file drop.  Does your browser redirect to `~/testpage.html`? If so, the `form` is being submitted

Comment: @Martin - No it doesn't go to `testpage.html`

Comment: As you're not using it, remove the `<form>` tag completely.

Comment: Did you try to add return false inside `$(".upload-area").on('drop', function(e){})`;

Answer (score 0):

Put submit button in hidden format. Follow below steps.

In HTML,

```
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" style="display:none;">
```

In Javascript,

```
function submitMe() {
  $("#submitBtn").trigger("click");
}


$(".upload-area").on('drop', function(e){
     ----
     ----
     submitMe(); 

});
```

Comment: That still refreshes my page. I don't want my page to be refreshed when I upload an image

Comment: use <form action="#"  ...>

Comment: submit button should be inside the form tag.